# echo with pipe in sh script creates filename with "?"

Tags: echo, pipe, filenames, sh

I'm confronted with a rather strange problem an echo command causes in a script.
It's supposed to be really REALLY basic stuff, but still, there's something "off".

Suppose, I have this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# SERVERPID='cat lite_server_pid.txt'
# kill -9 $SERVERPID
nohup java -Xmx3G -Xms2G -jar tekkit_lite_065.jar nogui > output.txt &
echo $! > lite_server_pid.txt
```

Yes, this starts my own little Minecraft/Tekkit-Server. ;-)

The Problem is, the file thats created is (for some reason) named

```
lite_server_pid.txt?
```

and YES, this includes the "?"! Doing the same command in shell, a file without ? is correctly created! Also, the content of the file is the desired processID.
Still, the ? following the filename is a major problem...
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Check your file for DOS line endings. I suspect that `?` is actually your terminal's attempt to display a carriage return (`\r`). Since `bash` expects UNIX-style newlines, the carriage return part of the DOS newline (`\r\n`) is treated as a legal character for the file name.

Run your script through `dos2unix`.

Comment: Thank you, chepner!!
This was the solution - I humbly admit, that I first created the script using windows Notepad. Later on, I used vi to edit it, but the carriage return remained hidden somewhere. 
Notepad - Never again!  ;-)